# Como faço para usar uma condição precedente no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Estou com dificuldades para usar duas colunas como condição no where.
Não sei se vou conseguir explicar direito, mas:

WHERE P.PROFILE_STATUS = '1' AND
      P.JOBTITLE NOT IN (' - CodRodrigo','Administrador','Manager','Support Staff','Teste Para Join - CodRodrigo') AND
      (P.JOBTITLE = 'PRESTADOR DE SERVICOS' AND SUBSTR(P.CORPORATE_ID,0,1) = 'P')

Na linha  (P.JOBTITLE = 'PRESTADOR DE SERVICOS' AND SUBSTR(P.CORPORATE_ID,0,1) = 'P') eu só quero as linhas que o primeiro digito do corporate id seja igual a "P" quando o Jobtitle for 'PRESTADOR DE SERVICOS'.

Mas esse scrip exclui todos os jobtitles que são diferentes de 'PRESTADOR DE SERVICOS'.
Eu quero excluir apenas os que são JOBTITLE = 'PRESTADOR DE SERVICOS' e que o primeiro digito do corporate id seja igual a "P".

Comment: Tenta SUBSTR(P.CORPORATE_ID,1,1) = 'P')

Comment: Creio que você precisa definir melhor como combinar suas condições. Talvez WHERE P.PROFILE_STATUS = '1' AND P.JOBTITLE NOT IN (' - CodRodrigo','Administrador','Manager','Support Staff','Teste Para Join - CodRodrigo') AND NOT (P.JOBTITLE = 'PRESTADOR DE SERVICOS' AND SUBSTR(P.CORPORATE_ID,0,1) = 'P') seja o que procura.

Comment: o NOT resolveu! Muito grata @anonimo